# I am getting no return data using ColdFusion and jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, coldfusion

I am getting a blank response. I even hard code a response. I use firebug and copy the location with parameters and it shows a response when i paste it in my browser.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySubmitButton").click(function(){
        var zipCodeFilter = $('input[name=zipCodeFilter]').val();
        var zipRadius = $('select[name=zipRadius]').val();
        var querystring = "zipCodeFilter="+zipCodeFilter+"&zipRadius="+zipRadius;
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://dev.lead-hub.com/datasource/dataAccess.cfc?method=getZipCodes&returnformat=json",
                data: querystring,
                success: function(response){
                    var resp = jQuery.trim(response);//getting alot of whitespace in my return CFC method
                    alert(resp);
                    return false;
                    if (resp == 'true'){
                        $('#loginResponse').html("<span style='color: green;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;'>Success!!</span>");
                        // you'll want to put your code here to move onto the next page. I would simply do a page refresh
                        // and continue with using the session's login data
                    }else{
                        $('#loginResponse').html("<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;'>Failed!!</span>");
                    }
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }
);
```

Code For CFC:

```
<cffunction name="getZipCodes" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="zipCodeFilter" required="true" type="numeric">
    <cfargument name="zipRadius" required="true" type="numeric">
    <cfset var local = {} />
    <cfset local.getZipCodes = "" />        
        <cfquery name="local.getZipCodes"  dataSource="#application.dns_live#">
            SELECT h.*
            FROM tbl_zipcodes g
            JOIN tbl_zipcodes h ON g.zipcode <> h.zipcode
            AND g.zipcode = '#arguments.zipCodeFilter#'
            AND h.zipcode <> '#arguments.zipCodeFilter#'
            WHERE g.GeogCol1.STDistance(h.GeogCol1)<=(#arguments.zipRadius# * 1609.344)
        </cfquery>
        <cfset local.returnString = "Good" />
    <cfreturn local.returnString />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I hard coded <cfset local.returnString = "Good" /> to see if I can return something using createObject component

Comment: Is this page hosted on same domain i.e. the Url for the page where you have this code starts with dev.lead-hub.com including http?

Comment: in the fire bug can u see a response?

Comment: Using firebug, do you see the request being made? And, also within firebug, when you use the preview feature, do you see the content you expect?  Are there any JS or HTTP errors?

Comment: I am using json. I blank response in firebug. No javascript error except for that POST. Yes it is hosted on the same server/domain.

Comment: Regarding your comment about "getting a lot of whitespace", you need to set the "output" attribute to "false"--both on the <CFCOMPONENT> tag and on the <CFFUNCTION> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting a blank response in firebug, but you see the value you expect when you access the URL directly in the browser, it strikes me as a possible caching issue.  Try adding "cache: false" to your ajax setup:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://dev.lead-hub.com/datasource/dataAccess.cfc?method=getZipCodes&returnformat=json",
    data: querystring,
    success: function(response){
        var resp = jQuery.trim(response);//getting alot of whitespace in my return CFC method
        alert(resp);
        return false;
        if (resp == 'true'){
            $('#loginResponse').html("<span style='color: green;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;'>Success!!</span>");
            // you'll want to put your code here to move onto the next page. I would simply do a page refresh
            // and continue with using the session's login data
        }else{
            $('#loginResponse').html("<span style='color: red;font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;'>Failed!!</span>");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

*edit*

Since that wasn't it - another thought occurred to me.  You say it works for you when you paste the parameters in your URL and request it directly.  That means you're requesting your method with a GET request, passing the parameters in the URL scope.  This is different than your ajax request, since that is type: "POST".  Try changing your ajax to type: "GET" and see if you start getting something back.